# Best practice for creating savable characters dynamically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a party based game where the player could have between 1 and 8 characters. I'm trying to make a sensible, elegant system for storing those characters stats and more importantly, their inventories of scriptable objects.

At the moment, I am using a serialized script containing a list of the character objects in my game, which are just empty gameobjects with the CharacterInventory scripts attached.

I want to make the CharacterInventory scripts dynamically, so I can make extra characters as needed. I can't work out how to add individual instances of the script to the savable list. I know that scripts cannot be instanciated.

I could create an empty gameobject via script and add the script to it during the creation process, but is there a more elegant solution?

Would scriptable objects work for the characters, given that they should contain lists of more scriptableobjects that are changed dynamically as well?

Comment: Just a hint as this ia quite a broad question. You can create non script code in unity as well. So you could just have a normal class character and save the characters in some other entity in a list or something like that.

Comment: What Mirko means is that your code does is not *required* to have `: MonoBehaviour` and could, in fact, extend other things. [For example...](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/PlayerInfo.cs#L23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general rule that you can follow is that you should separate your `Data` and your `Views`.

I do not recommend `ScriptableObject` as your only Data source cause it has some limitations. It can only serialize data that Unity does for you. but with the following approach, you can store almost everything you want.

You can or should use `ScriptableObject` but it would be much more powerful when used with another Data source like `files`.

Then you can easily save and load data.

Use `MonoBehavious` as View Layer and plain c# scripts as Data Layer.

For example, consider this Data class:

```
public class CharacterModel
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Level;
        public List<string> Inventory;
    }
```

And This as View class :

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private CharacterModel model;

        public void Save()
        {
            // I would use Json.net to serialize the model
            // Note: this is just a simple and non-efficient of saving all characters
// data, don't use it in production
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(model.Name, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));

        }

        public void Load(string characterName)
        {
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharacterModel>(PlayerPrefs.GetString(characterName));
        }
    }
```

Or you can save all characters as a single `file` and during the scene initialization fill your main `ScriptableObject`.

Based on this idea you can save all characters whenever you want and fill the characters scriptable object when you want to load characters data.

Comment: Re the comments: namely "don't use playerprefs." You have full access to the file system and an `Application.persistentData` path. Use it.